# Sort document by integer Firestore Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sort documents by `img` in descending order.
I've tried to add indexes in firebase console. Here is a screenshot from indexes tab: [image: user Ascending img descending]

Here is my database structure:
[image: database structure]

Here is my code:

```
db.collection("images").whereEqualTo("user", uid).orderBy("img", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it.isEmpty) {
            Log.i("Image", "Sorry, no image")
        } else {
            for (task in it) {
                Log.i("Image", task.get("img").toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is log:

```
I/Image: 2
I/Image: 1
I/Image: 3
I/Image: 4
I/Image: 6
I/Image: 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Have you checked this ? https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

It seems that your order function is not properly used. Also make sure that whatever you use from the above for ordering matches the type of index you create as mentioned here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data

Without understanding the text in the image you have(looks Russian), it seems that you need to order based on value or on child.

Comment: This is a Realtime Database's documentation, and I use Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that as stated on the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) there could be two explanations behind the behavior you are experiencing:

> 1. If you have a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field
> 2. You cannot order your query by any field included in an equality (=) or in clause.

Based on the following snippet provided on the documentation:

```
citiesRef.whereGreaterThan("population", 100000).orderBy("population").limit(2)
```

You could try the following (but I'm not sure if it'll work because of 2.):

```
db.collection("images").whereEqualTo("user", uid).orderBy("user").orderBy("img", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get()
    .addOnSuccessListener {
        if (it.isEmpty) {
            Log.i("Image", "Sorry, no image")
        } else {
            for (task in it) {
                Log.i("Image", task.get("img").toString())
            }
        }
    }
```